# Code re-use through Javascript Prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm a bit confused with how to achieve code re-use with the prototypal inheritance. I'm following the example at http://alexsexton.com/?p=51 where it create a Speaker object and bridge it with jQuery.

Say I want a new speaker that is similar to the one in example, but now with a extra sound file. The only code I can think of is like:

```
var AnotherSpeaker = Object.create(Speaker);

$.extend(true, AnotherSpeaker, {
    init: function(options, elem){
        this.options.soundFile = options.soundFile || this.options.soundFile;
        Speaker.init.call(this, options, elem);
    },
    options:{
        soundFile: 'abc.wav'
    },
    _playSound: function(){
        //....code to play the sound this.options.soundFile;
    },
    speak: function(msg){
        this._playSound();
        Speaker.speak.call(this, msg);
    }
});

$.plugin('AnotherSpeaker', AnotherSpeaker); //jquery plugin bridge
```

But this approach actually sounds quite 'classical' to me. I'm calling the 'super' through `Speaker.xxx.call`. I think I'm suppose to do **differential inheritance** but can't figure out how? Any help?

Comment: Emulating class-based OOP in javascript to get reuse doesn't work very well. There's a good article [Transitioning from Java Classes to JavaScript Prototypes](http://michaux.ca/articles/transitioning-from-java-classes-to-javascript-prototypes) by Peter Michaux you might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good article. But it seems to me that it finally settled on using mixins rather then the prototypal inheritance (no prototype chain to keep). So when should we use prototypal inheritance?

Comment: When you want to create multiple instances of an object. I rarely use them, most who have used javascript for a few years work out that the module and similar patterns are all that is required most of the time. I think because web applications are so dynamic, it is easier to keep it simple and re-write just what's required for updates rather than having complex inheritance chains and interdependence that need to be maintained. Re-use through snippets seems to work best.

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing differential inheritance (specifying what's different about `AnotherSpeaker` as opposed to `Speaker`).

Regarding your issue with the "supercall" to `Speaker.speak` via `call`: Yes, that is a pain. Supercalls are an area where JavaScript doesn't help you very much out-of-the box. With the structure you're using, that's probably going to be the best way to do it.

A couple of years ago [I defined a system](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) for making supercalls both easy and efficient. It involves using a helper function to create the constructor functions (I call them classes in the article, an artefact of my not having made the class-to-prototype transition in my head yet at the time), but aside from the terminology it is actually prototypical inheritance. You may find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When object orientation was new, it was common to think that inheritance is good for code reuse. Newer wisdom is that inheritance creates high coupling, and that reuse is often better enabled with aggregation instead of inheritance.

I couldn't reach the article you linked to, so I can't be more specific to your case.