# Call prototype's overridden method which then calls the next prototype's overridden method error

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to override methods of an object but still call the prototype's original method using `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. This works great the first time, but if the method is overridden more than once there are problems.

This code results in a stack overflow:

```
A =
{
   blurg: function()
   {
      puts('hey there')
   }
}

B = (function buildB(){
   var obj = Object.create(A)

   obj.blurg = function()
   {
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this).blurg.apply(this, arguments)

      puts('hai!!!!')
   }

   return obj
})()

b = (function buildb(){
   var obj = Object.create(B)

   obj.blurg = function()
   {
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this).blurg.apply(this, arguments)

      puts('bye bye')
   }

   return obj
})()


b.blurg()
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donut2d/QpAFy/)

The problem is that I want to call the prototype's method with the current object as `this`. This causes problems when that method does the same thing.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a way I could create a helper function for making sure the correct prototype is pulled up? I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827989/code-re-use-through-javascript-prototypal-inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in JavaScript, by nature, `this` always refers to the bottom down object instance in a prototype chain, so when you override methods in a hierarchical structure like above, `this.prototype.someMethod()` refers to the exact base class of the object instance, it doesn't seem to be a problem when you have maximum of two levels of hierarchy, however when you define  three levels of hierarchical structure or more, recursion is inevitable! here's how:

```
A: grand super class
B: super class - inherits from A (B.prototype = A)
C: class - inherits from B (C.prototype = B)

a: instance of A (defines someMethod)
b: instance of B (defines someMethod, calls A.someMethod through Object.getPrototypeOf(this))
c: instance of C (defines someMethod, calls B.someMethod through Object.getPrototypeOf(this))
```

When `b.someMethod` is called, it can successfully call A's someMethod (`Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` returns A when called by b)

However when `c.someMethod` is called, it first calls `b.someMethod`, which in turn calls `b.someMethod` because `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` always returns B when called by c! And here's where stack overflow occurs.

To resolve this, try to store a base class reference whenever you define a new sub-class, avoid using `this` when calling a super-class method:

```
A =
{
    blurg: function () {
        console.log('hey there')
    }
};

B = (function buildB() {
    var obj = Object.create(A);
    var base = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

    obj.blurg = function () {
        base.blurg.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('hai!!!!')
    }

    return obj
})();

C = (function buildb() {
    var obj = Object.create(B);
    var base = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

    obj.blurg = function () {
        base.blurg.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('bye bye');
    }

    return obj
})();

C.blurg();
```

Comment: Thanks! You explained that much more elegantly than I did. Storing a "base class" reference is a lot simpler than what I was imagining. Now, is there a more "prototypal" way of doing this? As simple as this solution is, it does seem a bit of a hack or an implication that I'm going about things the wrong way.